# Unity - procedurally change curvature of a quad?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural

Alright, I currently have a flat quad and would like to add a script that procedurally increases/decreases the curvature of the quad. By curved quad I mean:

[image]

This would be a lower curvature value:

[image]

and this would be a higher curvature value:

[image]

I've found this script for procedurally determining the corner radius of a quad in Unity C#: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1007222/round-procedural-square-mesh-corners-c.html

however I dont have much experience w procedural mesh generation and don't know how to dive into this.
How can I create a procedural curvature modifier in Unity/where can I start?

Comment: There are many different types of curves in math, so lets make sure you we pick the right one for you. Do you want this specifically to be a quadratic curve, or do you want this to be an arc of a circle? Mathematically they are very different.

Comment: @pseudoabdul I believe quadratic curve - these are supposed to be panels in VR, so the curvature should range from 180 degrees to less than 360.. probably around 210 degrees max

Comment: You can't measure quadratic curves like that due to the fact that the radius of curvature is not uniform throughout the curve. It sounds like you want an arc of a circle as your  curve. Before I can help you anymore, you will have to get that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use rotation of vectors from the middle of the quad view from the side to the extreme edges.
For example,
V = rotate(some vector, Delta angle)
V1 = rotate(V, Delta angle * 2) + shift to align the tail with V
and so one.

If you want to know more about runtime mesh generation you can check out my game mathematics series:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrtqd9jHm30NsA24NgkkcZHY8yjquBCVN